# Adding HTML content from a list into a Web Part

Tags: 2007, web-part, list

I have a page which is created from a Page Layout.  On the right side I need to have a Web Part which displays promotions e.g. html content. This html content comes from a list. Whenever I change the list content the pages should also should reflect this change.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Content Query Web Part to aggregate the banners from your Banner list.

Answer (score 0):

Presently i am doing the same thing i was thinking of any other possible solutions. I have read the citroen uk case study where they have mentioned about how they have done this .

http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/case_study_detail.aspx?casestudyid=4000003851

Relevant excerpts

To help increase manageability and efficiency, Dot Net used Office SharePoint Server 2007 to develop screens that Content Administrators use to automatically manage banners, videos, or images that appear on the sides or bottom of some site pages. Citroën wanted to be able to specify which banner could be inherited by a particular site or pages, so administrators could place the same banner on numerous pages without having to define it multiple times.  Dot Net developed custom fields in Office SharePoint Server 2007 to allow administrators to define a banner, and then specify which pages would inherit that banner, including time and date parameters.

i dont know how the above things are done.
Can somebody let me know

Comment: Still smells like CQWP or DVWP in the page, querying the list of banners for a column (that has multiple selections), and picking out the appropriate list items with certain entries in this column.